# Building gstreamer_ndk_bundle

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, gstreamer

I'm trying to build gstreamer_ndk_bundle under Ubuntu 12.4 and I'm failing miserably! I have installed all "glib-dev" packages (packages that in their name have `glib` and `dev`), and also I have tried to compile/install glib 2.33.1 (latest) from source, but I always get this error:

```
/home/marko/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/jni/../glib/gobject/gmarshal.c:149: undefined reference to `g_value_get_schar'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/marko/gstreamer_ndk_bundle/obj/local/armeabi/libgobject-2.0.so] Error 1
```

This means that glib source doesn't have the definition for `g_value_get_schar`, and since that function was introduced in glib somewhere after version 2.30.0, my guess is that I am not using proper glib!

I tried to force gstremaer_ndk_bundle to build with sources from the folder `/home/marko/glib-2.33.1/` which I compiled/installed by exporting these env vars:

```
GLIB_GENMARSHAL=/home/marko/glib-2.33.1/gobject/glib-genmarshal 
GLIB_COMPILE_SCHEMAS=/home/marko/glib-2.33.1/gio/glib-compile-schemas
```

Also I changed `gmarshal.h` so it includes `gmarshal.h` from the installed glib folder:

```
#ifndef _marko_glib_loaded
#define _marko_glib_loaded
#include "/home/marko/glib-2.33.1/gobject/gmarshal.h"
#endif
```

But failed in both cases.

- How can I know what glib is used while compiling gstreamer and install the proper one?
- How can I force gstreamer_ndk_bundle to use glib sources from the folder I have un-tared/configured/installed and not the system ones, or whatever ones it uses?
- I read somewhere that I need `gstreamer-devel` package if I keep getting this error while compiling. Where can I find that package?! Can't Google it out...
- Has anyone EVER built gstreamer_ndk_bundle and lived to tell the tale?

Answer (score 0):

I set `--enable-debug=no` flag in `glib/Android.mk`. And the link error is gone.
Try this.
P.S. You have to start `./setup.sh` to reconfigure all the packages.